# What does synchronous vs asynchronous loading mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, amd, commonjs

Reading from this [site](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_mixing-named-and-default-exports), I understand that using commonjs means that when the browser finishes downloading your files, it will have to load them up 1 by 1 as they depend on each other. But with AMD, it can load multiple ones at the same time so that even if file a depends on file b, it part of file a can be executed before file b is finished?

> CommonJS Modules: The dominant implementation of this standard is in
>   Node.js (Node.js modules have a few features that go beyond CommonJS).
>   Characteristics: Compact syntax Designed for synchronous loading and
>   servers
>
> Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD): The most popular
>   implementation of this standard is RequireJS. Characteristics:
>   Slightly more complicated syntax, enabling AMD to work without eval()
>   (or a compilation step) Designed for asynchronous loading and browsers

Answer (score 6):

Synchronous programming is executing code line by line. Same with loading.
It will load 1 by 1 whatever that you are loading.
Real world example: You are in a queue in cinema for a movie ticket.
Asynchronous would be many people in restaurant. You order food and other people order food. They dont need to wait for your order to finish.
Everyone can order but you dont know when the order will come. Same as with loading. You can load multiple things at the same time or different intervals but it doesnt guarantee that it will come in that order.
I hope the explanation is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax with CommonJS in loading modules is as such:

```
var MyModule = require("MyModule");
```

As you can see, this will block the thread until the module is downloaded, from either your filesystem or the web. This is called *synchronous* loading. This is impossible to achieve in a normal web browser environment without affecting user experience, since we cannot block the thread as the browser uses the thread to update the graphics.

With RequireJS, it's done as such:

```
// In your module
define(["dependencies", ...], function(){
    return MyModule;
})

// In your web page
require(["dependencies", ...], function(MyModules, ...){
    // do stuff here
});
```

With this model, our web page does not depend on the timing of when the module should be loaded. We can load our scripts in parallel while the page is still being loaded. This is called *asynchronous* loading. Once the scripts are loaded, they will call `define` which notifies RequireJS that the scripts are indeed loaded and executed. RequireJS will then call your main function and pass in the initialized modules.

Comment: So with requireJS, the graphics can still be updated with whatever code is already loaded and executed and then when other code is loaded and executed it will tell the client to update the graphics again?

Comment: @stackjlei With RequireJS, yes, graphics (and everything else) can still be updated and your browser will not hang. On the other hand, the CommonJS syntax cannot be used directly because the browser will freeze while the script is downloading, so normally your code would be transpiled which combines all the scripts into one file. RequireJS is great for loading scripts dynamically. In a nutshell, async means "running in a different thread" (though technically it's still the same thread.) Some people might call sync *blocking* and async *nonblocking*.